# Reach Owin Self Hosted app in Azure from outside Azure

Tags: .net, azure, owin

I have the standard OWIN Sample Console App in .NET with
an Startupclass, Listening on Port 80.

Running this app on an an Standard Windows Azure v2 VM
(Ressource Manager)

I added an Endpoint for Port 80 and opened the firewall on
port 80.

I can run this sample on the VM with the local ip or localhost:80.

I can not call the address from outside the VM

I can ping port 80 on the VM from outside Azure.

Question: I can not call the address (public ip / or assigned cloudapp address) from
outside Azure. What am I missing?

Thanks

```
var url = "http://+:80";

    using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running on {0}", url);
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: "*I can ping port 80 on the VM from outside Azure*" - no, you cannot. Azure does not support ICMP from external traffic.

Answer (score -1):

As I know, we can not directory access self hosted app from Azure outside. I searched the following workaround to achieve this purpose:

1) [Service Fabric Web API services with OWIN self-hosting](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi/)

2) [self-host an OWIN applications inside a Microsoft Azure worker role](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/host-owin-in-an-azure-worker-role)

3) [Running an OWIN Self-Hosted Web API in a Windows Docker Container](http://anthonychu.ca/post/web-api-owin-self-host-docker-windows-containers/)

4) Install IIS, deploy web API application to Azure VM.